# ios - how to get the UITabBarController to render after adding it to the application?

Tags: ios, ios5, uitabbarcontroller

I added the UITabBarController to the application using the storyboard, and I connected it to the existing views which I want the user to be able to jump to.

But I am a bit confused about how to make the tas at the bottom apear on every screen?  What is the step that I am missing?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you make the tab bar controller the root view controller of your window?

Comment: @rdelmar no, I wasn't sure about that part. Should I do that for every screen I want the tab controller to appear on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tab bar controller should be the root view controller for your window (there is usually only one window in an iOS app). Any other view controllers should be added as children of the tab bar controller (with setViewControllers:). You add one view controller to the viewControllers array for each tab.  The order you add them determines the order of the tabs. The tab bar controller presents the tabs at the bottom of every screen while these child view controllers present the views above the tabs.

Comment: sorry, kind of confused, do you mean I should make the tabbarcontroller the root view controller of every single window?  How do I do that?

Comment: Unless you have a very odd app, there is only one window -- I think you're confusing windows with views. You make it the root view controller in the application delegate, or I think you can just do in the storyboard (I don't have much experience with storyboards, so I'm not sure how you do it in IB).

Comment: If you've added the tab view controller manually (not from choosing the tabbed app template when you first created the project), then in IB, choose the tab view controller and select the "Is Initial View Controller" check box in the attributes inspector.  Then you shouldn't have to do anything in code.